# alert() with new line not used when message comes from an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element

```
<div id="msg" data-message="new\nline"></div>
```

when I try to alert using the following javascript.

```
alert($('#msg').attr('data-message'));
```

The alert does not perform the new line. Instead displays it exactly as it is in the div attribute.

```
Output: new\nline
```

How can I get the new line to work?

Doing this directly does work:

```
alert('new\nline');
```

Trying `\\n` did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `\` is escaped in your string, so try:

```
alert($('#msg').attr('data-message').replace(/\\n/g,"\n"));
```

Comment: Or just: `.replace("\\n","\n")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is, but it's an old problem I've had to deal with before. Try this.

```
var message = $('#msg').data('message');

var messageParts = message.split("\\n")

alert(messageParts.join("\n"));
```